# Performance considerations for joining a big table multiple times

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with 1.5 billion rows and 40 columns containing event codes, which are integers that need to be joined with a table called "code_mappings" to be decoded into meaningful information. Since this is a static table only updated annually, we want to convert the event codes to strings for easier analysis by data analysts. The code looks like this:

```
SELECT
  user_type_id,
  user_type_str.value as user_type_id_str,
  user_source_id,
  user_source_str .value as user_source_id_str
  ...
FROM
  events
left join code_mappings as user_type_str on  user_type_str.code = user_type_id
left join code_mappings as user_source_str on  user_source_str.code = user_source_id
...
```

I have a couple of questions:

- Many of the "_id" fields are 0 and do not map to anything; is there a way to optimize these? Can the code be optimized?
- The "code_mappings.code" column is unique. In a different DB engine, adding "code_mappings.code" as a primary key and all the "_id" as foreign keys would improve performance. While I know Snowflake does not really enforce these constraints, would adding them improve performance in this case?

Comment: have you measured performance? Please post a query plan

Comment: to "optimize the 0" don't use a valid number to indicate null use null, is the standard answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Filtering out as much unneeded information with a WHERE clause as early as possible will reduce the number of rows you have to join but that may only work for rows that have "0" for all 40 columns containing event codes; I'm assuming all 40 columns for that row would have to be in your WHERE clause filtering for "_id <> 0". Keep in mind, this will exclude those rows from the final result set, so if you need those rows you could split out the rows with 0 into a different table using a CTE and UNION ALL them back into your final result set.
2. Regarding the usage of constraints in Snowflake, you're correct that Snowflake doesn't enforce primary and foreign key constraints like other DB engines do. Adding these constraints won't actually improve performance since Snowflake only checks them at the time of their creation and not for future inserts or updates. Adding constraints in general decreases performance because you have to enforce them. Constraints are used for data integrity NOT performance.
3. Join Order & Type matters. Make sure you use the correct join types (LEFT, INNER, etc.). The order in which tables are joined can influence performance. It's usually more efficient to join smaller tables first.
4. Sometimes this isn't always an option, but if you're able to, you should use a larger warehouse for more compute; this should probably be your last option.

Comment: I'm afraid there are no rows that have all 40 codes to 0. I also need to keep all the rows hence the "left joins". I am not afraid about computing time I just know that this query is going to take a long time but I just wanted to be sure that at least it was going to be as optimized as possible before running.

Comment: Also, as @Simeon Pilgrim mentioned, if "0" is NULL then keep it as NULL if it will never be mapping to anything, that may help, but as always look at the query execution plan.